# Mouseover on Event day cell in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to show a pop up details of the event when i mouseover on event cell not on event bar line.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1):

eventMouseover

Triggered when the user mouses over an event.

function( event, jsEvent, view ) { }

event is an Event Object that holds the event's information (date, title, etc).

full documentation : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventMouseover/